services.dockeroperator Additional property attach is not allowed Docker Compose
I have below docker-compose.yaml
name: mydemo

    volumes:
      operator-volume:
        driver: local
    
    services:
      dockeroperator:
        build:
          dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - operator-volume:/terraform/dev
          - ./.kube:/root/.kube
          - ./utils:/operator/examples
        attach: false
        env_file: ".env"

when i am running docker-compose build , i am getting below error:
services.dockeroperator Additional property attach is not allowed
I have below versions:
$docker version
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
$docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.7.0


According to the Compose documentation, attach: was added to the Compose tool in Docker Compose version 2.20.0, which was released on 11 July 2023.  If your Docker installation is from 2022, it's probably too old to support this.  docker compose version will have its own version number, and that's the important version to check.
Older versions of the Compose tool supported putting metadata in the Compose file to indicate what version of the file format was in use, so Compose could warn you immediately if the version of the tool is too old.  This would also be compatible with other implementations like Podman Compose.  In spite of its utility, Docker has removed this check from newer versions of Compose.  I might write something like version: "4.0+2.20.0" at the top of the file for clarity on what specific version of the tool is required.

yes my docker compose version is old:  Docker Compose version v2.7.0
